# Output decodeURIComponent string won't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my AngularJS script, I transform part of an URI using VanillaJS `decodeURIComponent` like this:

```
var someVar = decodeURIComponent(uristring); //uristring = Zao0%2B1
```

But when outputting `someVar` using `alert()` or placing in inside of an input field, I keep getting `Zao0%2B1` instead of `Zao0+B1` as an output. What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your input is incorrect for the expected result.

If we take the expected result and encode it  a different value is returned than what you are using as input

```
var str = "Zao0+B1"// your expected output
// encode it
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(str); 
console.log(encoded);// "Zao0%2BB1" - differs from your input

// decode it
var result = decodeURIComponent(encoded);    
console.log(result); // "Zao0+B1" - same as original and as per expected result in question
```